# Indexing base class attribute overrides: cls -> value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to create a hierarchy of classes and efficiently lookup them by common class attribute value. So far I've come up with this solution:

```
class IndexedAttr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cls = None
        self.name = None

    def find_cls(self, value):
        cls_by_value = self.cls.__cache__[self.name]
        return cls_by_value.get(value)


class IndexedAttrMixin:
    __cache__= {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cache = cls.__cache__
        for name, attr in cls.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attr, IndexedAttr):
                if name in cache:
                    raise ValueError(f'Attribute {name} is already in the index')

                attr.cls = cls
                attr.name = name
                cache[name] = {}
            elif name in cache:
                cache[name][attr] = cls
```

Usage example:

```
class AuthBase(IndexedAttrMixin):
    auth_type = IndexedAttr()

    def __call__(self, session):
        raise NotImplementedError


class BasicAuth(AuthBase):
    auth_type = 'basic'

    def __init__(self, login: str, password: str):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password

    def __call__(self, session):
        print('Authorized using basic auth')


class NtlmAuth(AuthBase):
    auth_type = 'ntlm'

    def __init__(self, local_password: str):
        self.local_password = local_password

    def __call__(self, session):
        print('Authorized using NTLM')


auth_cls = AuthBase.auth_type.find_cls('ntlm')
auth_cls('password123')(None)
```

My questions are:

1. Are there more elegant/efficient solutions? For example, for now you'd have to import two objects, i.e. may this be implemented with only one class or maybe decorator?
2. Is *indexing* a correct term for this functionality?
3. How can I add support for type hinting? For now, I can't write `auth_type: str = IndexedAttr()`, because it'd cause a warning at this line: `auth_cls = AuthBase.auth_type.find_cls('ntlm')`

Comment: Please explain what the code is used for, that will help us write better reviews.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to implement a "dynamic new": create an object of a class using a string to choose the class object to create.  For example:

```py
auths = { 'basic': BasicAuth, 'ntlm': NtlmAuth }
cls = auths['ntlm']
cls('password123')(None)
```

... except you are trying to hide & automate the creation of the `auths` dictionary using `__init_subclass__`.

## Init Subclass

You are using `__init_subclass__` wrong.

First, the `**kwargs` parameter passed into `__init_class__` is supposed to be passed on to the parent's `__init_subclass__` method:

```py
    def __init_subclass__(cls, ..., **kwargs):
        ...
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        ...
```

Second, you are increasing the work of the author of every authentication subclass.  Each author has to remember to add this extra `auth_type` class member to their class definition.

What you should be doing is passing the `auth_type` into the `__init_subclass__` method.

```py
class AuthBase:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, auth_type: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.auth_type = auth_type
```

If you try to run the code now, you'll get:

```
    class BasicAuth(AuthBase):
TypeError: AuthBase.__init_subclass__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'auth_type'
```

Note, this is generated when Python is trying to define the class.  Your code doesn't try to create a `BasicAuth` object, so this error is telling the class author there is a problem even before someone tries to use the class.

To fix the issue, we need to pass the `auth_type` into the subclass creation:

```py
class BasicAuth(AuthBase, auth_type='basic'):
    def __init__(self, login: str, password: str):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password

    def __call__(self, session) -> None:
        print("Authorize using basic auth")
```

Notice the class attribute `auth_type` is no longer present.  Instead, we're passing `auth_type` as a keyword parameter to the `AuthBase.__init_subclass__` through the class definition syntax.

Make a similar change to `NtlmAuth`.

## Dynamic New

Since I've ripped out `auth_type = IndexedAttr()` from `AuthBase`, the class selection logic `auth_cls = AuthBase.auth_type.find_cls('ntlm')` will no longer work.  Let's fix that.

```py
class AuthBase:
    _auth_types: dict[str, 'AuthBase'] = {}
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, auth_type: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if auth_type in cls._auth_types:
            raise ValueError(f"Auth-type {auth_type} already exists")
        cls._auth_types[auth_type] = cls
```

Now `AuthBase` has an `_auth_types` mapping from names to classes.  I've omitted `cls.auth_type = auth_type`, since it isn't being used, but you can add it back in if needed to go from class back to the auth-type name.

Now we just want to lookup the desired subclass in the `AuthBase` dictionary based on the desired `auth_type` key, so let's add a `@classmethod` to `AuthBase` to do a `__getitem__` on that key.  Starting with Python 3.7, there is support for a [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__class_getitem__#object.__class_getitem__) method.

```py
    def __class_getitem__(cls, auth_type: str) -> 'AuthBase':
        return cls._auth_types[auth_type]
```

Now `AuthBase['basic']` returns the `BasicAuth` class, and `AuthBase['ntlm']` returns the `NtlmAuth` class.  Moreover, the typehint system knows that `AuthBase[]` requires a `str` key, and returns a `AuthBase` value, as desired.

## Resulting Code

```py
class AuthBase:
    _auth_types: dict[str, 'AuthBase'] = {}
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, auth_type: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if auth_type in cls._auth_types:
            raise ValueError(f"Auth-type {auth_type} already exists")
        cls._auth_types[auth_type] = cls

    def __class_getitem__(cls, auth_type: str) -> 'AuthBase':
        return cls._auth_types[auth_type]

class BasicAuth(AuthBase, auth_type='basic'):
    ...

class NtlmAuth(AuthBase, auth_type='ntlm'):
    def __init__(self, local_password: str):
        self.local_password = local_password

    def __call__(self, session) -> None:
        print("Authorize using NTLM")


auth_cls = AuthBase['ntlm']
auth_cls('password123')(None)
```

## Options

It isn't necessary to use the `*,`  in `def __init_subclass__(cls, *, auth_type: str, **kwargs)`.  You could instead write `def __init_subclass__(cls, auth_type: str, **kwargs)`, which would give you the flexibility to omit the `auth_type=` keyword in subclass declarations: `class BasicAuth(AuthBase, 'basic')` and `class NtlmAuth(AuthBase, 'ntlm')`.

## Corrections

The above code works, but doesn't type-check in mypy (or apparently PyCharm).

### `__init_subclass__`

While [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) suggests `super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)` to chain subclass initialization, that predated type-checking.

> The base class object contains an empty `__init_subclass__` method which serves as an endpoint for cooperative multiple inheritance. Note that this method has no keyword arguments, meaning that all methods which are more specialized have to process all keyword arguments.

Since type-checking now verifies the parameters being passed, the subclasses apparently cannot rely on dynamically splatting of `**kwargs`.  For instance, in a class hierarchy B -> D, the class D must be updated if a new parameter is added to B.  Type-safety comes with a higher maintenance cost.

Corrected method:

```py
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, auth_type: str):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        if auth_type in cls._auth_types:
            raise ValueError(f"Auth-type {auth_type} already exists")
        cls._auth_types[auth_type] = cls
```

### `Type['AuthBase']`

My bad.  The dictionary contains the `Type[AuthBase]`, not objects of type `AuthBase`.

```py
from typing import Type

class AuthBase:
    _auth_types: dict[str, Type['AuthBase']] = {}
    
    ...

    def __class_getitem__(cls, auth_type: str) -> Type['AuthBase']:
        return cls._auth_types[auth_type]
```

### `__class_getitem__`

The method `__class_getitem__` is [reserved by PEP 560 for typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/#specification).  Otherwise it would have been a clever hack.

### Update Code

```py
from typing import Type

class AuthBase:
    _auth_types: dict[str, Type['AuthBase']] = {}
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, auth_type: str):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        if auth_type in cls._auth_types:
            raise ValueError(f"Auth-type {auth_type} already exists")
        cls._auth_types[auth_type] = cls

    @classmethod
    def get_class(cls, auth_type: str) -> Type['AuthBase']:
        return cls._auth_types[auth_type]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()        

    def __call__(self, session) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class BasicAuth(AuthBase, auth_type='basic'):
    ...

class NtlmAuth(AuthBase, auth_type='ntlm'):
    def __init__(self, local_password: str):
        self.local_password = local_password

    def __call__(self, session) -> None:
        print("Authorize using NTLM")


auth_cls = AuthBase.get_class('ntlm')
auth_cls('password123')(None)
```

Comment: PyCharm gives the following warning:
`Signature of method 'AuthBase.__init_subclass__()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'object'`

Comment: See update at bottom of post.  Sorry about that.